# How to include Origin in requests?

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I would like to request a website which including my origin source:

i.e.

```
Host: https://webwebweb.com
Origin: https://somewebsite.com
```

I can request by running something like:

```
import requests
URL = 'someurl.com'
data =  requests.get(URL)
```

So which parameter I can add my origin then?

Answer (score 3):

`Origin` is a header, so you can add like so :

```
requests.get(
    URL,
    headers={'Origin': ORIGIN}
)
```

The docs for [request](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) from request and [http headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin)